# update values of two Columns in SQL database using C#

Tags: c#

```
cmd.CommandText = "update  dbo.diagnosis SET id=" + SetValueForText + "ss=" + sh;
```

where `sh` and column `ss` are of bool datatype and `id` and `SetValueForText` are of int datatype.
exception is invalid syntax near `ss`.

Comment: **USE parametrized queries!** to avoid SQL injection attacks and improve performance. ...

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a comma between the first value and the second column name. You should also be using a parameterized query to protect against SQL Injection Attacks:

```
cmd.CommantText =
    "update dbo.diagnosis set id=@id, ss=@ss";

cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SetValueForText);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ss", sh);
```

Also keep in mind that you're not filtering any values so this update statement will update every row in the table.

Comment: Justin please tell mee wherei have to put comma?